# How to use NDCG for multiclass classification problem

Tags: scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I have 20 different labels and they are [0, 1, 2, ..., 20]. Let's say that I have 5 samples and their predictions are: [2,1,17,9,6] and true_labels are [3,2,15,7,4].

```
from sklearn.metrics import ndcg_score
predictions = [2,1,17,9,6]
true_labels = [3,2,15,7,4]
ndcg = ndcg_score(references], predictions)
```

The code given below throws this error:

```
ValueError: Only ('multilabel-indicator', 'continuous-multioutput', 'multiclass-multioutput') formats are supported. Got multiclass instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Followed the [docs:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ndcg_score.html) `y_true array-like of shape (n_samples, n_labels)`

```
from sklearn.metrics import ndcg_score
import numpy as np
predictions = np.asarray([[2,1,17,9,6]])
true_labels = np.asarray([[3,2,15,7,4]])
ndcg = ndcg_score(true_labels, predictions)
```